# What is the best tool or technique to write doxygen code comments

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation

Public c++ header files must be provided with a lot of comments. It is hard to format and wrap doxygen comments. Does some formatting tool exists?

With features like auto wrap lines on 80th character, easy visual function grouping. Ideally documentation writer prepares a documentation separately, then inject it into or link using doxytags with code.

At this time we are using notepad/IDE to document the code.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say which IDE you're working with - If you're working in Visual Studio, then I've written an addin ([AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineer.com/AtomineerUtils.html)) that might help you - It generates/updates XML, Doxygen or JavaDoc documentation comments in your source files, and can word wrap and format the comments for you, minimising the work you need to do to keep them tidy. It also keeps the comments in sync with the code (parameters, type-params, thrown exceptions, etc).

(It supports C, C++, C++/CLI, C#, Visual Basic and Java, in Visual Studio 2010, 2008, 2005).

Comment: I love love love AtomineerUtils

Answer (score 2):

Emacs + [doxymacs](http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/) works fine for me.